# Unstable code due to submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - `project` and `todo` (project has many todos). I wrote a form that add the job to the project that is selected in the tray, but unfortunately, this addition is not always done. In the condition for my project, the submit button should be a link, which was implemented by me

```
<%= link_to 'OK', "#", :onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()" %>
```

The form work fine, until I changed the submit button to a link, and then sometimes it works normal, and sometimes it does not

```
<h1> Новая задача </h1>
  <%= form_with scope: :todo, url: todos_path, id: :form_id, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <% form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :text, placeholder: "Название задачи" %>
  </p>
  <%= form.select( :project_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, :id, :title)) %>
  <p>
    <a href="/projects">ОТМЕНА</a>
    <%= link_to 'OK', "#", :onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Also I tried to write a button like link_to in css, but due to the fact that I could not find the optimal thickness of letters, and I was forced to abandon such a maneuver.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use submit onclick?

Just use the usual submit:

```
<%= form.submit 'OK' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If link is only your requirement then instead of `link_to` just use `link_to_function` helper.

```
link_to_function 'ok', 'function_call_here'
```

Another thing is it is bad practice to put your jquery code on `on click` just use observer

```
$('#ok-link').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
  submit_your_form_here();
});
```

if your ok link is dynamic generated then change click with on function of jquery [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$( "#ok-link" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

> I would suggest just go with submit or button tag and make css proper according to your need.

You can find link_to_function description [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/link_to_function)

Comment: I did the way you recommended, I changed 2 files and nothing happened

application.js
    `//= require jquery`
    `//= require jquery_ujs`
    `//= require_tree .`
    `$('#todo_create_form').submit();`

index.html.erb
    `<%= link_to 'OK',  id: "todo_create_form" %>`